# Latex Includegrapichs and itemized linespace

Tags: latex

I want to make a `\newline` after the `\item[L1]` to make it seem like a header to the picture and not on the bottom left side. Help?

```latex
\section{Labbuppgifter}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[L1]
            \includegraphics[width = 0.6\linewidth]{L1.jpg}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post your issue on this LaTeX [site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\mbox{}` to set a blank entry for `\item[L1]`, followed by a paragraph break (an empty line) and then you can set your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[L1] \mbox{}

    \includegraphics[width = 0.6\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Of course, there are multiple other ways of achieving this. More detail in the question might provide more specific solutions.